# Historical Depth Data MtGox with higher granularity

Tags: bitcoin

I was doing some research and a need arized to get mtgox historic depth data, their api was not giving a lot of good info, it gives around ~6k bids and asks and most of them in last 3-4 months, while all of the dataset starts around 2010. I was looking for bid ask data with higher granularity, preferably for more currencies than just btc to usd.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can access MtGox's full historical trade data via Google BigQuery.

See here for more information:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=218980.0

I haven't seen anywhere that you could get the full order book history though.  That would be an absolutely massive data set if it existed, so I doubt if anyone has such a thing available.

Comment: By the way, those trades contain timestamped limit orders (the depth can be inferred).

Comment: Also see http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/is-there-a-historical-timeseries-of-market-depth-transactions-available/24742#24742

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a new software developed to download all historical data from various exchanges and currencies. The release date expected is October 2013.

More details here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=282154.0

Answer (score 0):

The latest source for MtGox's data feed is: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Pubnub
And PubNub's Bitcoin Exchange Solution Kit based on the above: http://rtbitcoin.co/